# How to set "MailingAddress" (address type) field on contact through Bulk API?

Tags: bulk-api, update, xml, address

I'm having problem setting the "MailingAddress" field on Contact sObject. I'm trying with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sObjects xmlns="http://www.force.com/2009/06/asyncapi/dataload" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <sObject>
      <carbide__CarburetorId__c>gid://carb-dev/Salesforce::Contact/3125</carbide__CarburetorId__c>
      <Id>003G000002HEIO5IAP</Id>
      <FirstName>Edgar</FirstName>
      <LastName>McClure</LastName>
      <AccountId>001G000001oy4xFIAQ</AccountId>
      <Title>cupiditate38 HUMAN</Title>
      <MailingAddress>
         <sObject>
            <Street>mailing_street</Street>
            <City>mailing_city</City>
            <State>mailing_state</State>
            <PostalCode>mailing_zip_code</PostalCode>
            <Country>mailing_country</Country>
         </sObject>
      </MailingAddress>
   </sObject>
</sObjects>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's subset of fields and you don't have to group them. They're only grouped by the UI. Just as you're populating all the other fields, it's no different for the address fields. Below are the names of each field:

```
<MailingStreet>Flinders St</MailingStreet>
<MailingCity>Melbourne</MailingCity>
<MailingState>VIC</MailingState>
<MailingPostalCode>3000</MailingPostalCode>
<MailingCountry>Australia</MailingCountry>
```